# Plotly: histogram with no fill color

Tags: visualization, plotly, histogram

I'm using Plotly's **graphic_objects.Histogram**. I am trying to draw several histograms on the same plot. I'm not satisfied with the results of the 'overlay' option. I would like to draw histograms with no fill colour like in [this example](https://statisticsglobe.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/figure-1-default-histogram-hist-function-in-R.png), with only the borders of the boxes drawn.

I was trying to fiddle with "**marker.pattern**" options but this doesn't seem to work. What would be the way to accomplish this, if this is possible?

Comment: Have you tried using the `marker` argument with a colour of zero alpha and only a line color?

Comment: Can you add in your code and screen shot the picture you are getting, so that others can reproduce your example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Oxbowerce's suggestion, this gives an OK look (however, ideally I'd like to only use the 'roof' of each bin and not the vertical lines, I suspect that's not possible though)

```
fig = px.histogram(...)
for i in range(len(fig.data)):
    fig.data[i].marker.line.width = 3
    fig.data[i].marker.line.color = fig.data[i].marker.color
    fig.data[i].marker.color = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)"
```